# Windows 10 Storage Spaces 2-Way Mirror Low Capacity Warning at 70%

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, raid, storage-spaces

I am not sure if this warning is a reason for concern or a reason to add more drives as suggested:
[image: Storage Spaces Warning]

I have this setup as a 2-way mirror, so that both drives should hold identical data. Both of them are of exactly the same size and both have the same 30% of space free. I therefore do not understand why is it telling me to add more drives, when in fact there is still 30% free space left and I am using a simple mirror for identically-size drives with no parity or other advanced options?

Using Windows 10 10586.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tells you to add two instead of one, that's why two.

Default threshold for this warning is 70%. You could try changing it via

`Set-StoragePool -FriendlyName "SS1" -ThinProvisioningAlertThresholds X`

in Powershell, where `X` is percentage of taken space for alert to occur. Documentation [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848672.aspx).

Comment: I understand that, but why is it complaining for a **2-way mirror**? I mean I understand why it would complain at 70% full with some other setup (different size disks, parity, etc.), but with this setup, if it is indeed a mirror, as they claim, there should be 30% free space on both drives and no reason to complain  about anything. That's what I don't get and what worries me. Is this 70% thing for all storage spaces just a sloppy design decision?